# Tensorflow model Ram usage rising continuously during test

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory

I've a simple model which try to predict captions of images. While encoding the images or fitting the model I don't have any RAM usage problems. However, while I predict to images' captions and saving them to the list ram usage rising continuously in Pycharm till 13GB. As I just have 1000 test images ( I'm using Flickr8K dataset) my ram is enough for me. However, I'll plan to work on the different datasets like Flick30K or MsCOCO. Another thing is that when I run exact code in colab I don't get any extraordinary RAM rising.

Computer specs:

- 16GB RAM
- Nvidia GTX 1060 6GB
- Windows 10

**My model:**

```
inputs1 = Input(shape=(OUTPUT_DIM,))
fe1 = Dropout(0.5)(inputs1)
fe2 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(fe1)
inputs2 = Input(shape=(max_length,))
se1 = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, mask_zero=True)(inputs2)
se2 = Dropout(0.5)(se1)
se3 = LSTM(256)(se2)
decoder1 = add([fe2, se3])
decoder2 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(decoder1)
outputs = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(decoder2)
caption_model = Model(inputs=[inputs1, inputs2], outputs=outputs)
caption_model.layers[2].set_weights([embedding_matrix])
caption_model.layers[2].trainable = False
caption_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

**Test code:**

```
actual, predicted = list(), list()
scoreDict = dict()
for z, y in tqdm(test_descriptions.items()):
    pic = encoding_test[f'{z}.jpg']
    image = encoding_test[f'{z}.jpg'].reshape((1, OUTPUT_DIM))
    pred = generateCaption(image)
    for d in range(len(y)):
       y[d] = y[d].split()
    actual.append(y)
    spl = pred.split()
    predicted.append(pred.split())
```

Comment: What is `generateCaption()` function?

Comment: You have not provided any explanation what are `z`, `y`, `encoding_test variables`, so check if you're not storing float32 versions of your input images anywhere in RAM. 13 GB for 1000 of 3-channel images encoded as 4-byte float gives me roughly 311x311 image size, which seems near the size of typical input to the neural network.

Comment: As you point I'm storing input images by `pic = encoding_test[f'{z}.jpg` . It is unneccessary for my purpose. Also as you predicted image size is 299*299

Comment: So is the problem solved after you cut any unnecessary data from remaining in RAM?

Comment: Yes. It was unneccessary, for the aim of this code. You point to the right place. Thanks.